# Keycloak configuration on startup cli script

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface, keycloak

I'm trying to configure a dockerized Keycloak server from a startup script I put on:

```
/opt/jboss/startup-scripts
```

I found the [CLI commands description](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/CLI%20Recipes.html#108626078_CLIRecipes-Adding%2CreadingandremovingsystempropertyusingCLI) to add properties as well as [some other examples](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.2/html-single/server_installation_and_configuration_guide/index#cli_recipes) but don't know which properties must I add/modify in order to, for example, add a realm to Keycloak.

Is there a complete listing of Keycloak configurable properties anywhere?

Comment: you can start your sever and and then shell into it and go to `jboss-cli` interactive console. Over there you can do `ls` that lists all the components including subsystems, then do `ls subsystems` to see the list of SS, e.g. `ls subsystem=keycloak-server` returns things that you can change

Answer (score 3):

The [Keycloak Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) supports execution of two types of scripts mouted to `/opt/jboss/startup-scripts`:

- WildFly .cli scripts.
- Any executable (chmod +x) script

Due to your links I assume you are interrested in the WildFly scripts.
I do not think that there is a complete listing of configurable properties for the WildFly application server used by the Keycloak Docker image. But you can [Get all configuration and runtime details from CLI](https://docs.wildfly.org/13/Admin_Guide.html#get-all-configuration-and-runtime-details-from-cli).

If you want to add a realm to Keycloak you can use the KEYCLOAK_IMPORT environment variable as described on the [Keycloak Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) page at "Importing a realm".